# Share the list created in 2 or more site

Tags: list, share

Good morning, I've created a list in a sub site.
The question is: How can I re-use the same list in another sub site?

Thanks 
Alex

Comment: Do you want a view of that list or just the same type of list in another subsite?

Comment: @Alex You could refer my answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Save it as template and upload to different site.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps below to move a SharePoint list from one site to another.

Step 1: Create a list template.

1. Go to the SharePoint list, click List> List Settings.
2. Click Save list as a template under Permissions and Management.

[image]

3. Enter a File name and Template name. Check the box if you want to “Include Content”.
4. Click the list template gallery link to go to the List Template Gallery page.

[image]

Step 2: Add the list template.

1. Go to Settings> Add an App.
2. Type the template name to add it.

**Note:**

- It may take some time for the app to be seen in all the sub-sites